How to prevent react csr from unloading the dom of a prerendered page
I have a Spa app built using React, for a better experience I use prerendering to get the full page, it performs well most of the time but flickers on slow networks because React unloads the page and regenerate it, is there any way to prevent it?
I tried using HydroRoot to hydrate the prerendered page but it didn't work, react didn't attach to the page and I'm not sure if react validated the difference between the two.
Another possible cause of the problem is that I'm using a lazy component, which is a must, I can't stand unwanted pages being loaded when entering the site.
Can anyone tell me how to solve it, here is a reproducible example: react-spa-prerender
